# Azure remaining credit value from API

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell, azure-cli, azure-management-api

Whenever I log on the azure web portal i get a notification saying `$xx.xx remaining credit`.

I would like to understand how I can retrieve this value using Azure API, az cli or Powershell.

I have tried using the following as advised by the support but unfortunately without luck:

```
accesstoken=$(curl -s --header "accept: application/json" --request POST "https://login.windows.net/$TennantID/oauth2/token" --data-urlencode "resource=https://management.core.windows.net/" --data-urlencode "client_id=$ClientID" --data-urlencode "grant_type=client_credentials" --data-urlencode "client_secret=$ClientSecret" | jq -r '.access_token')

subscriptionURI="https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$SubscriptionID?api-version=2016-09-01"

curl -s --header "authorization: Bearer $accesstoken" --request GET $subscriptionURI | jq .
```

The spending limit variable says just "on"

```
{
  "authorizationSource": "RoleBased",
  "subscriptionPolicies": {
  "spendingLimit": "On",
  redacted (too long)
```

Answer (score 2):

When you see "*$xx credit remaining*", it means your account has spending limit. There are many offerings which use spending limit mode. For example, you are given Azure Pass, or Microsoft Azure for Students Starter. Here is the list for reference (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/offer-details/).

In fact, Azure provides some REST APIs to let you work with Billing and Consumption but the API is limited to spending limit offerings. Advanced billing and consumption REST API are only fully supported for CSP (Cloud Service Provider) partner and Enterprise Agreement customers. That's said, with your current subscription, you cannot retrieve the balance summary (e.g https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/billing/enterprise/billing-enterprise-api-balance-summary).

However, there is a workaround to get usage details then perform SUM. To do so, first you need to retrieve billing period name
    https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingPeriods?api-version=2017-04-24-preview

Here is the sample response of my billing periods:

```
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "/subscriptions/2dd8cb59-ed12-4755-a2bc-356c212fbafc/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingPeriods/201805-1",
      "type": "Microsoft.Billing/billingPeriods",
      "name": "201805-1",
      "properties": {
        "billingPeriodStartDate": "2018-02-06",
        "billingPeriodEndDate": "2018-03-05"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "/subscriptions/2dd8cb59-ed12-4755-a2bc-356c212fbafc/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingPeriods/201804-1",
      "type": "Microsoft.Billing/billingPeriods",
      "name": "201804-1",
      "properties": {
        "billingPeriodStartDate": "2018-01-06",
        "billingPeriodEndDate": "2018-02-05"
      }
    },
```

...then get usage detail with the billing period name

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{Subscription}/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingPeriods/201805-1?api-version=2017-04-24-preview

{
  "id": "subscriptions/2dd8cb59-ed12-4755-a2bc-356c212fbafc/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingPeriods/201805-1/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails/cdd74390-374b-53cf-2260-fc8ef10a2be6",
  "name": "cdd74390-374b-53cf-2260-fc8ef10a2be6",
  "type": "Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails",
  "tags": null,
  "properties": {
    "billingPeriodId": "subscriptions/2dd8cb59-ed12-4755-a2bc-356c212fbafc/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingPeriods/201805-1",
    "usageStart": "2018-02-06T00:00:00Z",
    "usageEnd": "2018-02-07T00:00:00Z",
    "instanceId": "/subscriptions/2dd8cb59-ed12-4755-a2bc-356c212fbafc/resourceGroups/securitydata/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/2d1993southeastasia",
    "instanceName": "2d1993southeastasia",
    "meterId": "c1635534-1c1d-4fc4-b090-88fc2672ef87",
    "usageQuantity": 0.002976,
    "pretaxCost": 7.1424E-05,
    "currency": "USD",
    "isEstimated": false,
    "subscriptionGuid": "2dd8cb59-ed12-4755-a2bc-356c212fbafc",
    "meterDetails": null
  }
},
```

This returns list of each resource's usage and cost in JSON format and you need to SUM all **pretaxCost** value. This way would be complicated with PowerShell because you need to initialize objects, then deserialize JSON and perform MATH. With PowerShell, it can be done technically but requires C# experience.

Comment: if you mean something like this:
    $m = $apicall.content | convertfrom-json ; 
    $sum=0 ; $m.pretaxcost | select pretaxcost | % {$sum+=$_}
it does not return the same value as the used credit.
I think there is a significant delay when azure logs the usage

Please correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: @TaTo Yes you are correct. Usage from even Azure Portal has a delay. Recently I encountered a delay of 2 weeks. The actual I used was 1,4K but the portal show only 800 :). Just wanted to give you my case.

Comment: Do you mean the credit remaining notification when you log on the portal is not correct as well?

Comment: Yes that's! Encountered a few times and even raised MSFT ticket.